# Reaching object dynamically inside another object + arrays

Tags: php, oop

So I'm trying to figure out how to reach both SAIK's and FHC's amount of elements in the fenwick-object.

```
object(Match)[1]
  public 'duration' => null
  public 'teams' => 
    array (size=2)
      'SAIK' => 
        object(TeamResult)[2]
          public 'name' => string 'SAIK' (length=4)
          public 'goals' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public 'shots' => 
            array (size=27)
              ...
          public 'penalties' => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
          public 'players' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'fenwick' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      'FHC' => 
        object(TeamResult)[3]
          public 'name' => string 'FHC' (length=3)
          public 'goals' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'shots' => 
            array (size=29)
              ...
          public 'penalties' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          public 'players' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'fenwick' => 
            array (size=2)
```

count($match->teams['SAIK']->fenwick) does the trick but how do I solve it assuming I didn't know that "SAIK" was one of the teams? I've tried with teams[0] and such but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to put the result of the match into a database where SAIK is the home team with 5 fenwick scores and FHC the away team with 2 fenwick scores.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: what exactly do you want? you just can foreach through `$match->teams`?

Comment: You can get the keys contained in `teams` via `array_keys($match->teams)` or just loop over them via `foreach ($match->teams as $team => $team_properties)` as suggested.

Comment: I'm trying to put the result of the match into a database where SAIK is the home team with 5 fenwick scores and FHC the away team with 2 fenwick scores.